# Else if conditions are not executed properly

Tags: c

I am trying to build a small c program that asks the gender and the age of the user. So if the gender if 'F' and age>18 the message will be "woman" otherwise display "young girl" and likewise for the gender "M".
But according to my code only the two first conditions are executed properly then when coming to "else if" condition messages are wrong

Below is the code I wrote.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char sexe;
int age;

int main()
{
    if(age>=18)
    {
        printf("\n Woman");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n young girl");
    }

    return 0;
}
else if(sexe='M');
{
    if(age>50)
    {
        printf("\n Old man");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Young man");
    }

}
return 0;

}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps formatting your code to a readable indentation will tell you what's wrong. As written this can't even *compile*, much less run to incorrect output.

Comment: hint: `;` by itself is a valid C statement

Comment: How does this even compile?

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš it doesn't. No way this is the *real* code if the OP's claim it actually runs (incorrectly) is true.

Comment: @Gabjava - did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the main function before `else if`. Else if is not part of any function and this code should not even compile.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char sexe;
int age;

int main()
{
    if (sexe == 'F') 
    {
        if(age>=18)
        {
            printf("\n Woman");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n young girl");
        }
    }
    else if(sexe=='M')  // it is a mistake to put ; here that would mean empty statement
    {
        if(age>50)
        {
            printf("\n Old man");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n Young man");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

So the mistakes that you have made:

1) { } indicates block of code. You must be very accurate when to open one and when to close one.

2) `else if (sexe=='M');`
This means else if sex is M, do nothing.
`;` is an empty statement and it means do nothing.

3) `if (sexe == 'F')` is very different from `if (sexe = 'F')`

`==` means equality. Is the thing on the left side equal to thing on right side.
`=` means assignment. Make the thing on the right be the same as thing on right.

So if you write `if (sexe = 'F')` that means make sexe be 'F' and then
see if sexe is truthy value. Truthy value means expression that is regarded as true and I don't remember what is exactly falsy in C. I think it's `null` and `0` and empty string.

Comment: Tell me, how do your assignation in the `if` statements work for comparisons?

Comment: Good catch. I didn't write a line of C code in more than 10 years. I'll edit the answer

Comment: You need `==` for comparisons.

Comment: @RoadRunner: I think the whole world turns female when this code is executed, that's all.

Comment: Note that `sexe` is default initialized to 0 (`'\0'`) and `age` likewise — the testing/assignment is also erroneous, but the OP needs to think about how `sexe` and `age` are set to useful values.

Comment: That's understandable @JonathanLeffler.

Answer (score 0):

Your else if isn't executing properly because you haven't created the if statement if (sexe == 'F'), therefore your else if statement has nothing to be an alternative to. Also, you are returning zero before the else if (sexe = 'M'), this will end the function and because you are inside int main (), this will end the program.You are also using the wrong operator inside if (sexe = 'M'), you should use the double equals sign '==' operator in if statements. To fix your problem, add the if (sexe == 'F'), get rid of your first return zero and change the operator in if (sexe = 'M') I hope this helps!

One last thing, are you using an IDE? I don't think so because if you were using one it would have pointed out your operator in if (sexe = 'M') error. I can tell that you are a beginner in C and I strongly recommend to get an IDE, IDE's are very useful for pointing out errors in your code and are perfect for any programmer. In a language like C you will shoot yourself in the foot a lot so an IDE will help you on your way to being a pro. I use code::blocks for C programming but Visual Studio 2015 is a good alternative.

Comment: Thank you all you ! through your replies I've seen my mistake and I corrected it. But now the program is working well except that to the final message the output window does not stay is flashing. I am using right now turboC++ but planning to use code::block  as suggested my Max.
I've tried to go through the settings but found nothing.So in this case what should I do to keep the output window and see the whole results?

Comment: Which settings?